# Assigning data returned from promise to a variable object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have the following code which retrieves an object from AWS S3.

How would I assign the data returned from the promise to the `files` objects?

I would like to be able to pass the `files` variable to another method in the next `.then` as I would like to access the data.

```
var getFiles = function getFiles(files) {
    return Promise.all(files.map(function (file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var params = {
                Bucket: 'my-bucket',
                Key: file.key
            };

            s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }));
};


var fileNames = ['test.jpg', 'background.jpg'];
var files = fileNames.map(function(fileName) {
    return {
        key: fileName
    }
});


getFiles(files)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

Comment: Change `console.log(res)` in `then` to `files = res`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all(...).then` should return an iterable of the resolved promise return values, so `res` in the `then` handler should be an array of return values from `s3.getObject`.

`files` is global so you should be able to reference it from the `then` callback directly:

```
getFiles(files)
    .then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(files); // [{key: 'test.jpg'}, {key: 'background.jpg']
    })
    .catch(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

If `files` is subject to mutation between `getFiles` calls, you could pass it along the function chain by resolving it as the first argument to `Promise.all()` and then access it as `res[0]`

Comment: Within the getFiles function I would like to add the data from the getObject to a files.data key. I'm struggling to do this. Can you help?